# Copying a specific range to all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code, but I'm having trouble getting it to work properly.Instead of seeing C2:D5 as a range of ten items, I'd like to see C2 and cell D2 as a single item, and so on. Instead of ten items, the list will essentially consist of five. This is then copied to the appropriate cells D3:E3, as shown below. Is that even possible with vba?

````
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim startsheet As Worksheet
Set startsheet = wb.Sheets("start")

Dim r As Range
Set r = startsheet.Range("C2:D5") '

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Worksheets
     For i = 1 To r.Count
   If Not i + 1 > Worksheets.Count Then Worksheets(i + 1).Range("D3:E3").Value = r.Item(i,1).Value
      
     Next i
Next sh


End Sub   ```
````

Comment: It is possible, but i can't get your point what exactly you are aiming to achieve...

Comment: My goal is to copy the values of cells C2 and D2 (customer name and id) and then C3 and D3 and so on for each line of the list, to cells D3 and E3 from the next sheet until all items on the list are copied.

Comment: Do you want to copy each row of the `Source Range` (`C2:D5`) to the same one-row `Destination Range` (`C3:D3`) of each next worksheet starting from `.Worksheets(2)`? Is `.Worksheets("start")` actually `.Worksheets(1)`?

Comment: The startsheet is, in fact, the worksheet (1). The first sheet lists all of the customers' names, and the remaining sheets are in the format of a request form. That's why I'd like to duplicate one of the other worksheets with the same format (but not the first one). The code you sent me works perfectly, but if I add more items to the list, the new worksheet that is created is blank. @VBasic2008

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code was that you were using 2 loops when you only needed one. The loop for the sheets was unnecesary because you were already looping through sheets with the code "Worksheets(i + 1).Range("D3").Value"

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim i As Long

Dim startsheet As Worksheet
Set startsheet = wb.Sheets("start")

Dim r As Range
Set r = startsheet.Range("C2:D5")

Dim sh As Worksheet


For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    If Not i + 1 > wb.Worksheets.Count Then
        Worksheets(i + 1).Range("D3").Value = r.Item(i, 1).Value
        Worksheets(i + 1).Range("E3").Value = r.Item(i, 2).Value
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I will use `copy` method again, however I will assume the copy sheet is `sheet1` and you already created `sheet 2 -5` for the function, please try and see and modify for if statement in case you have other issue:

```
Sub test2()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim startsheet As Worksheet
Set startsheet = wb.Sheets("start")


For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    startsheet.Range("C" & i, "D" & i).Copy Worksheets(i).Range("D3")
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This code duplicates the entire list to all other sheets, whereas I want to duplicate the first item of the list to the second sheet, the second item of the list to the third sheet, and so on.

Comment: I have amended the code, it should be enough to solve your problem?

Comment: This works flawlessly. Indeed, the sheets for this function have already been created. Is it possible to create a check to see if there isn't a sheet available(more items on the list but not enough worksheets)? In that case the code can duplicate one of the previous worksheets ? Is this going to make the code "bulletproof," or is it going to make it too complicated? @kin Siang

Comment: Sure it can, I have amended the answer so that it will stop copy if the row is more than total count of worksheet...

Comment: @steven: Could you explain what you mean by *In that case the code can duplicate one of the previous worksheets*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily touch up the code to add sheets if you add more items to column C in startsheet. It'd be like this:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

Dim startsheet As Worksheet
Set startsheet = wb.Sheets("start")
LastRow = startsheet.Range("C2:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row

Dim r As Range
startsheet.Activate
Set r = startsheet.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(LastRow, 3))

Dim sh As Worksheet

For i = 1 To r.Rows.Count
    If i + 1 > wb.Worksheets.Count Then
        Set sh = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        Worksheets(i + 1).Range("D3").Value = r.Item(i, 1).Value
        Worksheets(i + 1).Range("E3").Value = r.Item(i, 2).Value
    Else
        Worksheets(i + 1).Range("D3").Value = r.Item(i, 1).Value
        Worksheets(i + 1).Range("E3").Value = r.Item(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: This runs perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Each Row to Each Next Worksheet

- If you opt for using `.worksheets(1)` then remove the `swsName` constant.
- Play with the values of the remaining three constants.

```vb
Sub CopyRowsForNext()
    
    Const swsName As String = "start"
    Const srgAddress As String = "C2:D5"
    Const dFirst As String = "D3" ' First Destination Cell
    Const wsFirst As Long = 2 ' First Destination Worksheet
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    If wsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(swsName)
    ' Maybe this would be more appropriate (forgetting about "start"):
    'Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(srgAddress)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To srCount
        cIndex = r + wsFirst - 1
        If cIndex <= wsCount Then
            wb.Worksheets(cIndex) _
                .Range(dFirst).Resize(, scCount).Value = srg.Rows(r).Value
        End If
    Next r

End Sub

Sub CopyRowsForEachNext()
    
    Const swsName As String = "start"
    Const srgAddress As String = "C2:D5"
    Const dFirst As String = "D3" ' First Destination Cell
    Const wsFirst As Long = 2 ' First Destination Worksheet
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsCount As Long: wsCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    If wsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(swsName)
    ' Maybe this would be more appropriate (forgetting about "start"):
    'Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(srgAddress)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim srrg As Range
    Dim cIndex As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For Each srrg In srg.Rows
        n = n + 1
        cIndex = n + wsFirst - 1
        If cIndex <= wsCount Then
            wb.Worksheets(cIndex) _
                .Range(dFirst).Resize(, scCount).Value = srrg.Value
        End If
    Next srrg

End Sub
```